# Excel VBA columns copy paste to next 12 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I got struck at some point where I don't know how to proceed further with the looping so here are the things I did

I had a excel workbook with different sheets sheet(Mcq Results), Sheet(Data_Neu) and Sheet(Chapters). I tried to use a code to get the chapters from chapters sheet to MCQ results sheet but I want this to be a continuous process until all the users(Operator_Name) are finished in MCQ results

A2 to A13 is chapter number.B2 to B13 is chapter name. C2 to C13 is Project number.

I want all this code to function until the Mcq Results (Operator_name) is empty

Attached you shall find the code.

Thank you.

```
Sub Chapters_Mcq()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set Sht3 = Worksheets("Chapters")
    Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Mcq Results")
    Sht3.Range("A2:A13").Copy
    Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sht3.Range("B2:B13").Copy
    Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sht3.Range("C2:C13").Copy
    Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by "until all the users(Operator_Name)" are finished in MCQ results. Unfortunately your questions is not very clear. Try to explain the structure of your sheets.

Comment: *until all the users(Operator_Name) are finished in MCQ results* Can you clarify?

Comment: This will not answer your question but will help with your coding: I would suggest removing the two  Application.ScreenUpdating = True from the middle of your code, and instead of copy and paste you can just reference the values:  Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = Sht3.Range("A2:A13").value

Comment: Yes Anit so, as I mentioned in the question I have 3 sheets in 1 excel workbook the loop has to work such a way that it should keep on copy and paste the rows that I mentioned in the above code until the sheet(Mcq results) operator_name is empty. To be precise the copy paste has to be performed until the MCQ results sheet Operator_Name is empty

Comment: I tried providing the For loop on the top as Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10 but I want this loop to be checking with Operator_Name instead of defined number as I = 1 to 10

Comment: Can you provide sample of your sheets? It will help to understand what you are trying to achieve. What would help even more is if you can provide a sample expected results sheet

Comment: So as I cannot insert the data sheet here I can provide the structure of my 3 sheets here which can help you to understand the structure of my issue  Sheet_Mcq results: Operator_Name Position Test_type Test_Date_audit Machine_Number Machine_Category Chapter Number_1 Chapter_Name_1 Max_Score_1 Min_target_1 Result_Post_test_1 Result_Score_1 Project number test_number Comment box TN_ID
Sheet_Chapter:  Chapter number Chapter Name   Project number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Sub Chapters_Mcq()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Sht3 As Worksheet
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i, j  As Integer
Dim LastBlankRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range


Set Sht3 = Worksheets("Chapters")
Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Mcq Results")

 'LastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
 'LastRow2 = Sht2.Range("G" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
 'NumRows = Sht2.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
 'Sht2.Activate


'LastBlankRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row

 For i = 1 To LastRow

LastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
LastRow2 = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value

If (LastRow2 = "") Then


'If IsEmpty(LastRow) = True Then

'Range("A1").Select


'Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sht3.Range("A2:A13").Value
'Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sht3.Range("B2:B13").Value
'Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sht3.Range("C2:C13").Value
Sht3.Range("A2:A13").Copy

  Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sht3.Range("B2:B13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sht3.Range("C2:C13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If
Next i
LastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
LastRow2 = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Row

If (LastRow = LastRow2) Then

Exit Sub

End If

End Sub'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly what you are trying to do but I'll try this:

```
Sub Chapters_Mcq()

    Dim Sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim i, last, lr1, lr2, lr3 As Long
    Set Sht3 = Worksheets("Chapters")
    Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Mcq Results")

    t = 2

    last = Sht3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Do Until t > last

    lr1 = Sht2.Range("G1").End(xlDown).Row
    Sht3.Range("A" & t & ":A" & t + 11).Copy
    Sht2.Cells(lr1+1, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    lr2 = Sht2.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
    Sht3.Range("B" & t & ":B" & t + 11).Copy
    Sht2.Cells(lr2+1, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    lr3 = Sht2.Range("M1").End(xlDown).Row
    Sht3.Range("C" & t & ":C" & t + 11).Copy
    Sht2.Cells(lr3+1, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    t = t + 12

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hallo Irene Thank you for sending me the code but unfortunately I am getting an error called Application definition or object definition error for the above code, could you please let me know the reason for the error ?

Comment: Just to add a point this code below is working but the problem is I cannot restrict the loop till the Sht2.A1 is empty                                   'For i = 1 To Sht2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row'

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or do you want to restrict the loop to a different value?

Comment: If I apply if statement I am not getting any error but the only thing is I want to restrict the value if the sht2.A1 is empty

Comment: I just tried this but instead of(For i = 1 To 10) I want it to be controlled as I=1 to sh2.A1 is empty

Comment: Have you tried Sht2.Range(“A” & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ?

Comment: Hi Irene, Could you explain me more about the above code. I did not tried above code

Comment: For i = 1 To Sht2.Range(“A1” & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  ??